# CSS Masonry in codepen shows one column less than specified

Tags: css, image, gallery

Here is a link to the codepen
http://codepen.io/yashrg/pen/GmhJj
Basically an image gallery that should show images in 5 columns.
I was using the seamless responsive photo grid tutorial from here http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

But the expected result is not what I expected. I only see 4 columns. Why could this be?

Comment: column-count is 4 (see .gallery in css) and if you wonder, why your menu does line-break: padding gets added to the width, so if you have 5 elements where each element has 20% width plus padding, you will have more than 100% (means one element will break in the next line)

Comment: Oh. That is just a silly mistake on my part. before posting the query on here, I was testing that it was an issue with 5 columns and not 4 or 3. So I forgot to change and SAVE it as 5 column.
As for the menu and the widths, I was using the box-sizing:border box property to try and keep the padding included in the widths so I didn't have to do that math.